# Reorder/shuffle values in a row/column in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to shuffle randomly, values in rows or columns in a excel sheet. Is there any function/macro for that?  How do i do this?

-ad.

Answer (score 33):

Hm... just as simple solution without programming.
For example, you have a column of data (A):

```
23
78
12
78
```

Just add another one column - B. Each cell of column B must be a function RAND():

```
A     B
--    --
23    =RAND()
78    =RAND()
12    =RAND()
78    =RAND()
```

Now you can sort rows by column B and get desired solution.

Comment: Simple and works well. Statistical validity needs to be tested though. PS: I ended up going with =RANDINBETWEEN(1,n_rows)

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume your values are in cells A1:A8

1. Enter the formula =RANDBETWEEN(1,100000)+ROW()/100000 in cells B1:B8

   Enter the formula =RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$8) in cells C1:C8

   Enter the formula =INDEX($A$1:$A$8,C1) in cells D1:D8

Every time you calculate (hit F9), a newly shuffled list will appear in cells D1:D8

Comment: @Ejames: I did not see a function RANDBETWEEN in my excel version(Office 2003). How do i get that function or am i missing anything?

Comment: @goldenmean: It is part of the "Analysis ToolPak" add-in, which comes with Excel, but isn't always enabled. If you do a search for RANDBETWEEN in Excel help, it provides some information on how to install it.